# How to set custom error message for Quota violation?

Tags: apigee

I tried multiple options of publishing custom error message for Quota violation. But I was not able to produce custom error message.

Please provide step by step process to generate custom error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Raise Fault Policy (but don't attach it to a flow):

   ```
   <RaiseFault async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Fault-Bad-Quota">
     <DisplayName>Fault-Bad-Quota</DisplayName>
     <FaultRules/>
     <Properties/>
     <FaultResponse>
       <Set>
           <Headers/>
           <Payload contentType="text/plain">My Custom Fault for {fault.name}</Payload>
           <StatusCode>500</StatusCode>
           <ReasonPhrase>Server Error</ReasonPhrase>
       </Set>
     </FaultResponse>
     <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
   </RaiseFault>
   ```
2. Add a Conditional Fault to your Proxy configuration

   ```
   <FaultRules>
     <FaultRule name="BadQuota">
       <Step>
           <Name>Fault-Bad-Quota</Name>
       </Step>
       <Condition>fault.name = "QuotaViolation"</Condition>
     </FaultRule>
   </FaultRules>
   ```

You can add a global fault policy to your proxy default.xml.  If you're using the UI go to the word "default" right under your target.

[image]